# Error al quere mostrar SnackBar

Tags: flutter

Estoy validando el inicio de sesión mediante **Firebase** a lo cual quiero mostrar un `SnackBar`..

### Validación

la declaración de la clase es la siguiente

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
    void submit() async {
        final auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
        if (_formType == FormType.login) {
            String userId = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                _email,
                _password,
            );
            if (userId == null) {
                print('User null------------>');
                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Revise sus datos e intentelo de nuevo'),
                );
                setState(() {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                });
            }
    }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Entra widget loginPage");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Form Page'),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: buildInputs() + buildButtons(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

pero al momento de mostrar el `SnackBar` manda lo siguiente

```
I/flutter (25112): Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
I/flutter (25112): No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
I/flutter (25112): There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
I/flutter (25112):   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
I/flutter (25112): A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
I/flutter (25112): A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the key.curre
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error muy común, eso pasa cuando se trata de usar el `SnackBar` usando el contexto que no tiene un `Scaffold` (como lo dice el error).

Ahora si revisas el código, si hay un `Scaffold`, pero Flutter espera que el contexto que sea usa esté en un nivel más abajo que en el que declaras el `Scaffold`(estás usando el mismo context).

Una de las formas de solucionarlo es usando `Builder` widget para obtener un nuevo contexto, quedaría así :

```
  void submit(BuildContext newContext) async {
        final auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
        if (_formType == FormType.login) {
            String userId = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                _email,
                _password,
            );
            if (userId == null) {
                print('User null------------>');
                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Revise sus datos e intentelo de nuevo'),
                );
                setState(() {
                    Scaffold.of(newContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                });
            }
    }
```

Y ya que no pones el botón que usas para llamar al método, voy a suponer uno, pero agregándole `Builder` como parent.

```
        Builder(
                builder: (newContext) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      submit(newContext);
                    },
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                  );
                }
              )
```